# If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} (f'(x)+f(x)) =L<\infty$, does $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) $ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to prove or disprove this problem:
If there exist $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} (f'(x)+f(x))=L<\infty$ then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) =L$.

When I assume problem below:

If there exist $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} (f'(x)+f(x)) =L<\infty$, There exists $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$?

I can use mean-value theorem to show that.

So my question is:

> If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} (f'(x)+f(x))=L<\infty$, does $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ exist?

Comment: Why did you include the same phrase thrice in your question? Couldn't everything after the first sentence be dropped without changing the meaning? (Also, you can use `\lim` in math mode to get $\lim$, and `\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}` gives $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$.)

Comment: @julien: I had to read it thrice, but there was a subtle difference. He was alleging that he *knew* how to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists in one of the statements. He was then asking how to show that limit must be $L$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Good point. I read too quickly, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the function $$g(x)=e^{x} f(x).$$ Then $$Dg(x)=e^{x}f(x)+e^{x}Df(x)=e^{x} \left( f(x)+Df(x) \right).$$
Now,
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{g(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{Dg(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} Df(x)+f(x)
$$
by De l'Hospital's theorem.

**N.B.** I think this exercise was solved by G. Hardy in one of his books.

Comment: Beautiful Proof. Thanks.

Comment: It's not mine, of course.

Comment: To apply l'Hôspital's rule, is it not needed that $\lim\limits_{x \to + \infty} g(x)=+ \infty$?

Comment: @Seirios I know that $\lim(e^x)=\infty$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Maddy No that's not sufficient to get $\lim g=+\infty$. Not every $f$ has $\lim_{+\infty}e^xf(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: So I am curious as to how we have $ \lim g = \infty $??

Comment: @Vishesh We have, unless $L=0$

Comment: What happens to this proof when $f$ is of exponential decay (to zero or otherwise)? I have a feeling that the L'Hospital step breaks down since $g$ may not go to $\pm \infty $.

Comment: In fact, we can suppose that $L>0$ (otherwise, consider $f+n$ for $n$ large enough). So there exists $a>0$ such that $g'(x)>a$ for $x$ large enough. If $g'$ is continuous, it is easy to deduce that $g(x)>a(x-x_0)$ and so $g(x) \to + \infty$. Otherwise, I don't know...

Comment: @CameronWilliams: In that case, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ anyway (or to $L$, where $L$ is the limit of the exponential decay). The proof above strictly proves the contrapositive - that if the limit of $f(x)$ doesn't exist, then neither does the limit of $f(x)+f'(x)$.

Comment: I second that. Thats what I feel too

Comment: To apply De l'Hospital's theorem, you just need the obvious fact that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^x=+\infty$.

Comment: @julien What missing argument?

Comment: @julien Definitely no: when the denominator diverges, you should not care of what the numerator does. It is the form [anything/$\infty$].

Comment: @julien Pick up Walter Rudin's *Priciples of mathematical analysis*. You'll read that "if either $f(x) \to 0$ and $g(x) \to 0$, or if $|g(x)| \to +\infty$, then..." I agree that the most interesting case of De l'Hospital's theorem concerns the case $[\infty/\infty]$, but it **is* true when the denominator diverges, *no matter* what the numerator does. Please consider that Wikipedia is not the best source for optimal mathematical statements :-)

Comment: Oh, that statement, I see what you mean, now. We were all commenting on the basis of the wikipedia statement. And I only wanted to point out that when $g'$ and $h'$ tend to $+\infty$, automatically $g$ and $h$ do as well, which is the case here, and does not require to look at $g$ and $h$ at all. Of course, Rudin's statement is better than wikipedia's.

Comment: What a wonderful proof. Do you have a more specific citation?

Comment: The statement, with a rather old-fashioned hint, appears as Exercise 32, page 246, of Hardy, *A course of pure mathematics*, Cambridge University Press, 1908.
I am pretty sure I studied this proof on another book, but I can't remember what book right now.

Answer (score 1):

When $f'$ is continuous, you can avoid l'Hôspital's rule by saying:

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \geq x_0$ implies $$L-\epsilon < f'(x)+f(x) <L+\epsilon$$

Hence $$(L-\epsilon)e^x < (f'(x)+f(x))e^x <(L+\epsilon)e^x$$
$$\int_{x_0}^t(L-\epsilon)e^xdx < \int_{x_0}^t (f'(x)+f(x))e^xdx <\int_{x_0}^t (L+\epsilon)e^xdx$$
$$(L-\epsilon)e^t-(L-\epsilon)e^{x_0} < e^tf(t)-f(0)<(L+\epsilon)e^t-(L+ \epsilon)e^{x_0}$$
$$(L-\epsilon) - (L-\epsilon)e^{x_0-t} < f(t)-f(0)e^{-t} < (L+ \epsilon)-(L+\epsilon)e^{x_0-t}$$

for $t \geq x_0$. When $t$ is large enough, we get $$L-2\epsilon < f(t) < L+2\epsilon$$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \to + \infty} f(x)=L$.

Comment: Why $(f'(x)+f(x))e^x$ is integrable?

Comment: Indeed, I added the assumption that $f'$ is continuous in my answer.

Comment: @ Seirios.There are discontinuous functions that are integrable too right??Doesnt this restrict the scope of the proof??