# How prove this $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f'(x)+f(x))=l$

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity

let $f(x)$ is continous and $f'(x)$ is continous  on $[0,\infty)$,show that

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f'(x)+f(x))=l$$
>   if and only if: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=l$ and $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$.

How prove this it? Thank you.

> I can prove this if $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f'(x)+f(x))=l$$
>   then we have  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=l$

**My Part of the
Solution**:

without loss of we let $l=0$,Give $\epsilon>0$,let $a>0$ be such that $|f(x)+f'(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\ge a$

Then by the generalized mean value theorem there is $\xi\in (a,x)$ such that
$$\dfrac{e^x f(x)-e^af(a)}{e^x-e^a}=f(\xi)+f'(\xi)$$
Thus
$$|f(x)-f(a)e^{a-x}|<\epsilon|1-e^{a-x}|$$
so
$$|f(x)|<|f(a)|e^{a-x}+\epsilon|1-e^{a-x}|$$
so
$$|f(x)|<2\epsilon$$ for sufficiently large $x$.

**But How can prove $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$**

**and other question: How prove if$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=l$ and $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$**

then we have

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f'(x)+f(x))=l$$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/407654/

Comment: @JonasMeyer, your link is same my solution,But my problem have other problem,But Thank you all the same

Comment: nanchangjian: Do you mean to hypothesize that $f'$ is also continuous? Otherwise this is false, because you can find differentiable functions $f$ satisfying the hypotheses with $f'$ discontinuous.  If $f'$ is continuous, then you may also refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-does-the-existence-of-a-limit-imply-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous.

Comment: Sorry,I'm very sorry,Now I have edit:becasuse this problem from chinese say:f(x)是连续可导

Comment: nanchangjian: I don't know Chinese, but according to Google Translate the translation to English is "continuously differentiable," which means $f'$ is continuous.  Thank you.

Comment: @JonasMeyer,Yes,Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1** If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=l$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=0$.

Thus, for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $a$ so that $|f'(x)|< \epsilon$ for $x \in (a, \infty)$. You also know that $f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,a]$ (why)?

**Hint 2** For the other question, try to apply the generalized mean value Theorem for $(x,x+a)$ when $a$ is very small and $x$ very large.

Comment: @JonasMeyer,yes,I agree with you,Thank you,

Comment: and dear @N.s.,can you post your all solution? Thank you

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yea missed that.

Comment: sorry,I have edit.Now can you post your all solution? Thank you