# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)+\int_{0}^xf(t)dt\right)$ exists, what about $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

Given that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty]$.

If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)+\int_{0}^xf(t)dt\right)$ exists

then evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407654/if-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-fxfx-l-infty-does-lim-limits) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648652/if-lim-x-to-inftyfxfx-l-show-that-lim-x-to-infty-fx-l-and?lq=1) may help. (Take $G(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ and note $f=G'$.)

Comment: It's similar to Barbalat’s Lemma!