# Property of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f$ - a continuous function and
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \int_0^x f(t)dt + f(x) \right) = 0$$
Prove that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337516/if-lim-x-to-infty-leftfx-int-0xftdt-right-exists-what-about-li).

Comment: @DavidMitra, thanks!